# Problem writing python script that can play videos on android app

Tags: python, android, automation, pyautogui, bluestacks

Python programmers please help!

I'm writing a script that can open an Android app and play videos one after the other continuously via bluestacks emulator.

I have written a code that can write the name of the app in the search bar below, close to start button.. I am using Windows 10...

After searching the app, the pyautogui has not been able to locate the screenshot.

I used pyautogui.locatescreenshot('C:\photo.png) , but is it saying the file is empty.

I used snipping tool to screenshot the image as I was unable to screenshot using pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot_example.png')

So the code that I have now can type and search out the app, but can't open or click it...

below is the code that I have written

import pyautogui

import time

time.sleep(2)

while True:
pyautogui.click(x=175, y=749)

pyautogui.typewrite("My App", interval=0.1)

pyautogui.click(1568, 789)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include more details to clarify what the problem is and format your code as codeblocks, so that we can better help you. Also see [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [How to format your Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)